# How can I make swanctl update resolv.conf?

Tags: vpn, dns, strongswan

I'm connecting to an IPSec VPN with strongswan and swanctl. I had some trouble getting it to work with the `ipsec` command, but after changing to `swanctl` instead, initiating the connection works fine.

My problem now seems to be that the DNS information is not updated. I can connect to the remote servers by IP, and name resolution works if I add the name servers to `resolv.conf` by hand, but `resolv.conf` is not updated automatically when I connect.

Strongswan comes with the [ResolvePlugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Resolveplugin) that should handle this, but I can not seem to get it to work. When I tried connecting with the `ipsec` command, the name servers got updated, so it seems that the gateway server is sending the information.

`swanctl --stats` reports that the `resolve` plugin is loaded.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS servers are only installed if they are received as configuration attributes, and these are only requested together with a virtual IP address (and, of course, the server must also be configured to send a DNS server back to the client). Check the log for what's actually going on (e.g. if servers are received, or if there is perhaps an error during installation of the received DNS servers).

Considering that the config you posted in [your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1267190/how-do-i-use-network-manager-to-connect-to-ipsec-vpn) does not contain `vips = 0.0.0.0` (see [VirtualIP](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp#Initiator-Configuration) on the strongSwan wiki) no virtual IP address will be requested from the server and, thus, no DNS servers either.  Try what happens if you change that. The VPN server has to be [configured accordingly](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp#Responder-Configuration) to assign virtual IPs and DNS servers to the clients.

Similarly, if you use the NetworkManager plugin you'll have to check the "Request an inner IP address" option to request a virtual IP and DNS servers.