# How do I use network manager to connect to IPSec VPN?

Tags: vpn, strongswan

I have set up a VPN connection with strongswan throught the command line, which works fine. I would like to use network manager instead, but I am having a hard time configuring it correctly. I am running Ubuntu 17.10.

This is the configuration I am using for the command line connection:

```
connections {
  myconnection {
    version = 2
      remote_addrs = 111.111.11.111
      local {
        auth = eap-mschapv2
        certs = certificate.pem
        eap_id = my-username
      }
    remote {
      cacerts = certificate-ca.pem
    }
    children {
      child {
        remote_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
      }
    }
  }
}

secrets {
  eap {
    secret = my-password
    id = my-username
  }
}
```

I have installed the strongswan network manager plugin. When I choose EAP, I can set a certficate for the gateway, but no others.

Is it possible to connect to this VPN gateway with network manager? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAP-MSCHAPv2 does not use client certificates. The `certs = certificate.pem`
 line you've currently configured is basically useless.

Just select the CA certificate in the GUI and enter the username (and optionally the password).

Comment: You were absolutely right, the client certificate was not needed. I've managed to set it up in network manager, so I'm going to accept this answer. I'm still only able to connect through the command line, but I'll create a new question for that, if I can't figure it out.